# Как полностью удалить программу?

Tags: qt

Всем привет. У меня стоит windows 8.1, я установил visual studio, qt creator, virtualBox, в virtualBox установил ubuntu и на него тоже поставил qt creator, но потом удалил всё. Перед установкой на сколько помню у было 412 Гб свободного памяти, но после удаления этих программ свободной памяти почему-то стало 375 Гб, а не 412 Гб как было до установки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связано? Я удалял через программы и компоненты

Comment: У вас остался файл с виртуальным диском, созданный программой VirtualBox. При удалении VirtualBox эти файлы не удаляются. Он должен быть где-то в Documents, AppData, Users - точно не помню. Можете удалить этот файл вручную, если он вам не нужен.

Comment: эту папку удалил, но он весил всего 112Мб

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нашел в папке пользователя установленный Ubuntu в virtualBox, удалил его и освободилось еще 28 Гб